# syntax error in an Ansible YAML playbook to download apache http in my localhost

Tags: ansible

```
---
- hosts: test_server
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: extract tar file
      command: tar -xvzf httpd-2.4.41.tar.gz 
    - name: go to the extracted directory
      command: cd httpd-2.4.41
    - name: Run below commands
      command:
         - ./configure --prefix=instance --with-mpm=worker --enable-proxy -enable-deflate --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-rewrite --enable-apr -enable-apr-util --enable-ssl --enable-setenvif --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl 
         - make
         - make install
     - name: change directory
       command: cd
     - name: check version
       command: /app/apache/instance/bin/apachectl -v
     - name: start httpd
       command: /app/apache/instance/bin/apachectl start
```

but I am getting below error

```
[root@91c2ebbd3d57 ~]# ansible-playbook test.yml
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected '-' indicator
```

The error appears to be in '/root/test.yml': line 14, column 6, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
     - make install
 - name: change directory
 ^ here
```

Comment: I formatted the YAML code and the input/output. Please feel free to adjust anything that I missed or mistook.

Comment: there is an indentation problem...  remove one space at the beginning of line number from 14 to line number 19

Comment: You are using the `command` module incorrectly. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/command_module.html My suggestion would be packing your commands into a script, use the `copy` module to copy it to the remote server and execute it.

Comment: Also, you should be using `unarchive` to unpack the `.tar`. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/unarchive_module.html

Comment: Another problem is using `cd`. You're most likely thinking of an ansible playbook as a script (which is why you're using `cd`), but most of the time it is not necessary. Check the ansible module index to find what modules you need (`make`for example).

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
---
- hosts: test_server
  remote_user: root
  tasks:

  - name: extract tar file
    command: tar -xvzf httpd-2.4.41.tar.gz 

  - name: Run below commands
    shell: |
      ./configure \
      --prefix=instance \
      --with-mpm=worker \
      --enable-proxy \
      --enable-deflate \
      --enable-proxy-balancer \
      --enable-rewrite \
      --enable-apr \
      --enable-apr-util \
      --enable-ssl \
      --enable-setenvif \
      --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl 
      make
      make install
    args:
      chdir: /root/httpd-2.4.41

  - name: check version
    command: /app/apache/instance/bin/apachectl -v

  - name: start httpd
    command: /app/apache/instance/bin/apachectl start`
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue (syntax error) is the indentation of the `- name: change directory` line and all the lines following that line.  They are all indented one single space too many.